# Javascript highlight/unhighlight word

Tags: javascript, html

I need to highlight a certain word in a HTML page. I have managed to highlight the element but I also need to unhighlight the previous word if a new word is searched. I have tried this, the highligth works, but it doesn't work the un-highlight.
The unhighlight part should unhighlight any lines containing span id='highlight'...etc, but not unhighlight the current word (!word).

```
//Unhighlight the previous searched word
var regex_old = new RegExp(\"<span id='highlight'><font style='background-color:#ffff00'>!\"+word+\"</font></span>\", 'gi')
var str_replace_old = word;
block.innerHTML = block.innerHTML.replace(regex_old, str_replace_old);

// Highlight the new word
var regex = new RegExp(word, 'gi');
var str_replace = \"<span id='highlight'><font style='background-color:#ffff00'>\"+word+\"</font></span>\";
block.innerHTML = block.innerHTML.replace(regex, str_replace);
```

Thanks.

Comment: An ID should only be applied to 1 tag. Please use a class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a class (eg: class=".current") to the current span which is highlighted.
while you highlight new word, check the class if it is having '.current' dont highlight and remove that class!! and add that class to new highlighted span!

so that you can identify current highlighted word, in order to unhighlight!!

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression to identify the search string and wrap a span around it makes sense, but you don't need to do the same for un-highlighting. Simply removing the class to  indicate that it is highlighted would do the trick. By the way, ID should be a unique attribute, so using a class to indicate "highlight" would be more appropriate. After you remove the highlight class from all spans, then you search the new string and give it the highlight span.